# Difference between writing file from /dev/zero and truncate

Tags: disk-usage, devices, truncate

```
$ timeout 1 cat /dev/zero > file1

$ wc -c file1
270422016 file1

$ du file1
264084 file1
```

Questions :

(1) How do 270422016 null characters come out to be 264084 bytes (i.e 258M).

```
$ truncate -s 270422016 file2

$ wc -c file2
270422016 file2

$ du file2
0 file2
```

Questions :

(2) `file2` has been created with same number of null characters as `file1` has, but the size of `file2` is zero, why?

(3) What did `/dev/zero` do that `truncate` didn't or vice versa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `du` does not show size in bytes, but (in this case) 1024-byte-blocks. So the numbers are actually identical ( `264084 * 1024 = 270422016` )
2. `truncate` creates a [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) provided the filesystem supports such things
3. `/dev/zero` actually produces infinite `\0` bytes which are then written to file, and writing zeroes consumes space like writing any other content. Another way of producing a file that consumes space *without actually writing zeroes* would be using `fallocate`.

You can use `filefrag` to get more information about such files.

```
$ timeout 1 cat /dev/zero > file1
$ truncate -s 270422016 file2
$ fallocate -l 270422016 file3
$ filefrag -e file1 file2 file3
```

---

File 1 (`cat /dev/zero`) is fully written, and also turned out to be fragmented in this case:

```
Filesystem type is: 58465342
File size of file1 is 270422016 (66021 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..    8175:    9983740..   9991915:   8176:            
   1:     8176..   32751:   11049359..  11073934:  24576:    9991916:
   2:    32752..   54271:   11193265..  11214784:  21520:   11073935:
   3:    54272..   62191:   11182601..  11190520:   7920:   11214785:
   4:    62192..   70383:   11214785..  11222976:   8192:   11190521: last,eof
file1: 5 extents found
```

Fragmentation depends on how much free space there is, and where the filesystem decided to start writing to the file not knowing how large it will turn out to be in the end.

---

File 2 (`truncate`) is just an empty shell, there is no space reserved for it at all, its size is merely indicated by metadata, not by physical extents.

```
File size of file2 is 270422016 (66021 blocks of 4096 bytes)
file2: 0 extents found
```

---

File 3 (`fallocate`) is allocated, but marked as unwritten. So physical space is reserved for it, and it's even unfragmented (as the filesystem was told the size beforehand). Reading this file will result in zeroes even though physically there may be different data stored at this address. This is because instant file allocation merely reserves space but does not overwrite data on disk.

```
File size of file3 is 270422016 (66021 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..   66020:   10983338..  11049358:  66021:             last,unwritten,eof
file3: 1 extent found
```

Comment: Great answer! "Another way of producing a similar file without writing zeroes would be using fallocate." You really go into the details later, but on first read my impression was that you were saying fallocate would write zeroes to the disk, which is not the case... Perhaps you'd want to add to this sentence, maybe to indicate in which ways this file is similar and in which ways it is different? Thanks!

Comment: @filbranden okay, I changed the wording, hope it helps